# HTTP Apache - how to set param in a Header for a secure cookie?

Tags: java, http-headers

Does anyone know if its possible to set a "Secure Cookie" inside a Header?

i need to create a cookie in a header like this Set-Cookie:JSESSIONID:893ihewwydkq2764@&@09;Path=/;secure

With the "secure" param at the end. I have looked at the Http apache Header class and all it takes is a name and value pair. what about aditional params such as "secure" ?

The purpose of doing this is so that the cookies can only be used on a encrypted connection ie on https:// only

I am devoloping in Java by the way. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, http headers are just that: key-value. For the Cookie header, the "value" is actually a list of key-value pairs itself (plus a bunch of other things usually)

However, if you are developing in Java, there is probably a better way to deal with cookies than by manipulating the headers directly. If you are using a framework, the framework probably makes it easier, but if you are working with raw servelets, the servelet spec also gives you better ways of dealing with setting cookies.

---

With the HttpClient package, you can definitely send secure cookies back to the server. The [SetCookie interface](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/cookie/SetCookie.html) can [set the cookie to be secure](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/cookie/SetCookie.html#setSecure%28boolean%29). That said, it's a *little* bit confusing that you are using HttpClient to *set* secure cookies (the server, not the client, usually does that) but you can still do it.

Comment: Im using Apache HTTP libraries and in particularly HttpClient method

Answer (score 1):

When you create a javax.servlet.http.Cookie in Java, use the [setSecure](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/api/javax/servlet/http/Cookie.html#setSecure%28boolean%29)() method.